# i want to remove java completely out of my centos machine, ie uninstall it completely

Tags: centos

Iam pretty new to centos operating system. iam trying to completely uninstall java from my machine. what is the command which will completely wipe out java from my machine. i have tried  but i think this is not the way to uninstall java completely.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I presume you have tried to remove it.  So what have you tried specifically?

Comment: "Yum remove jdk".

Comment: AT Ramhound.. if you don't know whether he tried anything to remove it  then your comment might suggest that he does try to remove it, which might not be a good idea.  And also, you write that you presume he has tried to remove it. You don't need to presume. As he wrote in his third/last sentence that he has tried but he thinks what he tried is not the way.

Comment: i'm no expert but if centos uses the yum package manager,  then you may want to look into the command to remove java with yum.  And after you try things, do a search for jthe java executable, see if it has been removed as part of any uninstallation process.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main forms in which Java is distributed

- Java Development Kit (jdk)
- Java Runtime environment (jre)

You probably need to tell `yum` to remove both of them.

It would be wise to check for dependents before doing this. `repoquery --whatrequires jre`

Also `yum list | grep java` can be interesting.

Comment: yum list produces 400 references containing "java" to wade through.